# I want to add if condition in kendo ui gridview Nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, nopcommerce-3.90

[image]

```
{
                                        field: "Id",
                                        title: "@T("Admin.Common.Download")",
                                        width: 100,
                                        headerAttributes: { style: "text-align:center" },
                                        attributes: { style: "text-align:center" },
                                        template: '<a class="btn btn-default" href="DownloadPdf/?downloadGuid=#=downloadGuid#" title="Download" ><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
                                    }
```

in template section I need if downloadGuid is not empty then Download icon will show otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to add If else condition in kendo grid we want to add # before and after condition.

```
template: '#if (downloadGuid!=null) { #<a class="btn btn-default" href="DownloadPdf/?downloadGuid=#=downloadGuid#" title="Download" ><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> # }#'
```